# Jack asked a "Hot" Question!

Tags: discussion

I don't know how the "hotness" algorithm works exactly, but Jack [asked a question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1190/67) that has a chance at drawing some network-wide attention:

[image]

Good work!